# Compile Rhapsody generated code outside of Rhapsody

Tags: uml, rhapsody

I'm have created few rhapsody models as part of my project at work . We have created class diagrams , state charts and panel diagrams and tested the model using simulation . After Simulation we have auto generated C++ code from the working models. 
So my question here is there a way to use External Compiler for Rhapsody generated code for example: Microsoft Visual Studio?

Comment: What should be an issue compiiing generated code???

Comment: Since the generated code will have rhapsody framework code its throwing bunch of errors if I try to run the cpp files in the S32 Design Studio for Power Architecture

Comment: It would help others to help you if you create a complete question showing the issues you have - error codes, code snippets, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Rhapsody always uses an external compiler for compiling the code (both with simulation and without), i.e. there is no compiler shipped with Rhapsody, it works with "adapters" that invoke external compilers. The adapter layer includes properties that tell Rhapsody how to generate code for a particular compiler, e.g., Visual Studio, VxWorks, Cygwin/gcc. When you generate make and run the code, Rhapsody creates both the main and the makefile, it runs the makefile to compile the code, and then runs the .exe that results. There is nothing to stop you running the compilation outside of Rhapsody. The key thing is that it will link your code with the OxF adapter framework code for the associated build environment (this abstracts away concepts such as threads, mutexes etc). Have a look at the Settings tab for the configuration you're using to build. There should be a MSVC option in the Environment pull-down list. This is Visual Studio. Note: When using MSVC option you also need to set a property to say which version. CPP_CG::MSVC::IDEVersion, i.e. on the service Rhapsody does allow what you want the main thing is that it's easier to let Rhapsody build the makefile as it does this in the code gen step. This is the "standard" way. There is also a platform integration, where Rhapsody creates the VS project file. Whether this will work may depend on version numbers etc. I'd try standard model-driven way first which is essentially command-line compiler invocation.

Comment: Hi Fraser, Thanks for the response . I have already linked Visual Studio and generated code .  But my problem is I have to take the generated cpp files and make it compile on the target hardware (ECU) . In order to do that I need to first compile it on the S32 Design Studio for Power Architecture and then take the executable (.elf) on to the target hardware .

Answer (score 0):

To run your Rhapsody code on a target you also need to compile the framework for this target. To do this you need to write an adaptor for this target. There is a pdf in the Rhapsody folders that explains all the steps.

For Visual Studio or Cygwin there is already a prepared framework. You may chose it in the component.

If you just want to habe your generated code in Visual Studio then right klick on your configuration and select "change to xxx ...". This creates a Visual Studio or Eclipse project for you with all the sources and Makefile.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're into Rhapsody RTOS adaption layer questions. Background: Rhapsody code generation follows a Model-driven Architecture approach to enable the creation of Platform-Independent Model separate from the Platform-Specific model (if you define the Platform as an embedded C++ target). If you use Rhapsody Developer to generate code like state machines then event queues for event are stored on the thread and you can use UML2 concepts like ports and interfaces and marking a composite class active (to make it run in a thread). The realization of the code that provides aspects such as threads (and timers) is provided by the OxF (Object-eXecution Framework) adapter layer (a set of classes that provide the RTOS specific code). Rhapsody has a set of RTOS it supports out of the box, but it is possible for a client to create a new adapater layer for a new target and add this to the Settings pull-down list (this also includes specifying properties to tell Rhapsody how to build/make for the RTOS). The adapter layer is a library that is statically linked with the application code and hence you need to build this library as well as providing the code. See the Introduction to Rhapsody Framework (OxF) in: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/groups/service/html/communityview?communityUuid=969f1342-9137-406d-81f5-7f082a7c646d#fullpageWidgetId=W7b708910613a_41a1_aa47_1cc06a5020ec&file=d5a0d94e-b3a0-494a-98c0-1238fff2ecc3. This assumes that you are using the full OxF. There are ways you can build without RTOS (minimal OxF or using Willert's toolkit) that may be applicable in certain domains (constrained microcontrollers etc), I don't know too much about your environment to know if it's possible. The first question is whether the target supports a full RTOS pattern, or whether a minimal RTOS approach is needed. The latter constrains how you model, hence is something you usually have to start with knowing up front.

Answer (score 0):

Rhapsody generates a makefile to build and link your project with the Rhapsody framework. I would strongly recommend that you re-use this makefile to externally build the project, rather than try to recreate it again elsewhere.

Taking the Dishwasher as an example, open the project in the Rhapsody IDE and "make" the project. Notice the output window prints the command used to build the project using the generated makefile (EXE.mak) and a pre-existing script (msvcmake.bat) for that environment. For example:

> ""C:\ProgramData\IBM\Rational\Rhapsody\8.4\Share"\etc\msvcmake.bat EXE.mak build x86 VC10 "

You can use a similar command to build your project on the command line.

Open a terminal and change to the configuration directory of the Dishwasher project (C:\ProgramData\IBM\Rational\Rhapsody\8.4\Samples\CppSamples\Dishwasher\EXE\Host)

Here is a modified version of the same command to rebuild the project:

> C:\ProgramData\IBM\Rational\Rhapsody\8.4\Share\etc\msvcmake.bat EXE.mak rebuild x86 VC10

*For reference:*

The project build command for each environment can be found in the property:

> CPP_CG:[Environment]:InvokeMake

The framework build command is specified in the property:

> CPP_CG:[Environment]:buildFrameworkCommand

In some cases you can copy the framework libraries from

> C:\ProgramData\IBM\Rational\Rhapsody\8.4\Share\LangCpp\lib

If you want to move everything to a new location you have to respect the makefile dependencies and retain the directory structures in the new location.

For example, it is possible to copy the Framework and Project sources along with their makefiles over to a remote target and build it there.